# iBeacon: Unable to detect broadcaster - Intermittent

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I came across this tutorial (http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-programming-ibeacons-tutorial/) about iBeacon which I found interesting. I've downloaded their source code and able to run well.

Anyway, I noticed one strange thing. There are times, when I run the broadcaster first instead of the receiver, the receiver seems to not be able to detect any beacon but if I run the receiver first, only then the beacon can be detected.

I've tried looking into other tuts but iBeacon seems like a new technology and not much reference can be found yet. Can any of you guys who had get their hands dirty into this iBeacon thing shed some light on this intermittent issue?

Your help are much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is because the receiver app only starts 'ranging' for beacons if it detects that you have entered a region. If you start the broadcaster first, you're *already* inside the beacon's region, so your app might not start ranging. This sentence in the article is the clue:

> Launch the receiver app and carry it far away from the broadcasting beacon and then walk towards it to simulate entering the region.

**Monitoring** for a beacon means that your app will only be notified when you *enter* or *exit* a region you've defined. The radius of this region could be up to ~50m, so if you're just sat next to the receiver, you shouldn't trigger one of these events unless you turn the receiver off and on again. Monitoring can be done whilst the app is running in the background or the foreground.

**Ranging** for beacons in a region means that the app will be notified *once per second* with a list of all beacons that the device can see in the specified region (ordered by distance). Ranging will call the `locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:` method of your `CLLocationManager`'s delegate. The list of beacons will be constantly updated as you move around inside / outside the region and your distance to the beacons changes. Ranging is intended to happen whilst your app is in the foreground.

If you would like the app to continuously listen for beacons, try calling

```
[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
```

in your `viewDidLoad:`, instead of in your `didEnterRegion:` method.

Comment: superb answer. +1 for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Its due to current location delegate available methods. Add this method also -

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
        [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}
```

This will fix the issue.